# text sms isn't being sent, even though toast shows that it's sent

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I am trying to send a text sms to all the contact numbers in my `ArrayList`. My code is as follows:

```
try{

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    if (customarray.size() != 0) {

          Log.d("contact",String.valueOf(customarray)); //shows all the contact numbers 

          for (int i = 0; i < customarray.size(); i++) {

             Log.d("contact",String.valueOf(customarray.get(i))); //shows each of the contact numbers

             sms.sendTextMessage(customarray.get(i), null, string, null, null);

             Toast.makeText(contacts.this,"Your sms has been sent to "+customarray.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();

   }
```

I have also added the permission in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Here, `customarray` contains all the contact numbers. Even though the toast shows up, that *"Your sms has been sent to..."*, but the sms never gets sent. Why?

Comment: You should add a `PendingIntent` and see if it's called with success or failure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Joachim Sauer, using `PendingIntent` works:

```
try{

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),contacts.class);

    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);

    if (customarray.size() != 0) {

          Log.d("contact",String.valueOf(customarray)); //shows all the contact numbers 

          for (int i = 0; i < customarray.size(); i++) {

             Log.d("contact",String.valueOf(customarray.get(i))); //shows each of the contact numbers

             sms.sendTextMessage(customarray.get(i), null, string, pi, null);

             Toast.makeText(contacts.this,"Your sms has been sent to "+customarray.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();

   }
```